# Java make GUI responsive

Tags: java, swing

how can i make my gui Window responsive?
I cant change the Layout Manager , otherwise i would need to change everything again.
Is there some way? Hope someone can help.

```
public ClientFenster() {
    fileQueue = new FileQueue();
    uploader = new BuildServerUploader();

    selectPathButton.addActionListener(new FileChooser());
    JLabelLogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("logo3.png")); //Logo

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    table1.setModel(tableModel);
    table1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table1.setGridColor(Color.gray);
    table1.setShowGrid(false);
    table1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    tableModel.addColumn("Date");
    tableModel.addColumn("Size");
    tableModel.addColumn("Status");
    tableModel.addColumn("Name Zip");
    tableModel.addColumn("Time");
    tableModel.addColumn("Project Name");
    tableModel.addColumn("User");


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClientFenster");
    frame.setContentPane(Fenster1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "responsive"?  Do you mean when you attempt to upload something (based on `BuildServerUploader`) the UI is unusable? The you need to go have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to better understand the issue and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: I believe he's referring to responsive resizing. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: jeah i mean the resizing .. if i maximize the window once , and then try to minimize , the components stay maximized. So in the end i cant rly use the window if i change the size , sorry for misunderstandings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a listener which would handle window/frame resizing events and set the table size according to the resized window/frame size.

Here are some useful links:

[How To Write A Component Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html)

[A video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJsjlucSoXM)

Comment: well i just made setResizeable(false) and set the size on my owm , its working , still thx guys